# List of wordpress posts

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, http

Is there a way I can get a list of all my wordpress posts on my server, preferably in JSON, using a GET request.

I would like to use this list on my main website and currently can't see how I can do it?

Comment: You'll probably need a plugin.  Never used it, but https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ might help

Answer (score 0):

> You can make the posts from wordpress to get as JSON objects

Ex: I am trying to get the posts from the type called **'product'**. The Coding looks like.

```
global $wpdb; 
$args = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID"; 
$products = $wpdb->get_results( $args ); $output = array(); 
foreach( $products as $product)
{ 
    $output[] = array( 'id' => $product->ID, 'title' => $product->post_title ); 
} 
echo json_encode( $output);
```

Or Another method you can do is that you can prefer the plugin called json API so that you can get all posts as API response.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Please check your table for data. Is there any post of post type products. if yes then the simple query should work

Comment: You can run this code in phpmyadmin directly. and see if any post is there. and please replace $wpdb with the prefix of you tables.